# Set content length of request based on content in node

Tags: node.js

How to set the content length of the request based on the content?

For example:

```
POST /Display HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 125

{"QueryReq":
  {
    "Tid": "Tid-123456",
    "SessionId" : "1350711351232058820" 
  }
}
```

On posting this request in telnet I need to press enter many times till the content length is `125` that is empty chunks are received in the server. How can set the content length automatically based on the request content?

Comment: you are doing post request in your node server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `Content-Length` header

```
var data = querystring.stringify({
  "QueryReq": { "Tid": "Tid-123456", "SessionId" : "1350711351232058820" }
});

var options = {
    host: xxx,
    port: xxx,
    ----
    ----
    headers: {
      'Content-Length': data.length
    }
};
```

Comment: please do not use data.length, I bumped to this issue and author said do not use data.length, instead, use Buffer.byteLength(data). Ref question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692580/node-js-post-causes-error-socket-hang-up-code-econnreset and ref issue: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1749

Comment: @NamNguyen is correct, I just spent ages with this [buffer issue](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_reasonphrase_headers). Also, you don't even need to set the length [Sending a 'Content-length' header will disable the default chunked encoding](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)