# Hubot with slack adapter - cannot perform rtm.start

Tags: http, slack-api, slack, hubot

I'm trying to have hubot + slack on my local machine.
installed hubot and slack client.
running:

> bin\hubot -a slack

and got error (after adding log messages to the script)

> INFO Connecting...
>
> INFO { ok: false,   error: { [Error: socket hang up] code:
>   'ECONNRESET' } }

from reading code in node_modules\slack-client\src\client.js 
found the problem occurs in a POST request:

```
   Client.prototype.login = function() {
     this.logger.info('Connecting...');
     return this._apiCall('rtm.start', {
       agent: 'node-slack'
     }, this._onLogin);   };




  Client.prototype._apiCall = function(method, params, callback) {
     var options, post_data, req;
     params['token'] = this.token;
     post_data = querystring.stringify(params);
     options = {
       hostname: this.host,
       method: 'POST',
       path: '/api/' + method,
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
         'Content-Length': post_data.length
       }
     };
     req = https.request(options);
```

tried to do: [Node.js POST causes [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692580/node-js-post-causes-error-socket-hang-up-code-econnreset)
 with no success

Comment: I can't find that code in current versions of that library... what version of `slack-client` did you install? Can you try installing the latest (2.0.4)?

Comment: @smarx , which hubot-slack version you are using  ?

Comment: I've never installed `hubot-slack`.