# Hubot with slack adapter

Tags: slack-api, slack, hubot

trying to install Hubot with slack adapter as written here:
https://github.com/slackhq/hubot-slack

in particular running this:

> npm install hubot-slack --save

but I'm getting this error when trying to load the bot:

> hubot -a slack
>
> ERROR Cannot load adapter slack - Error: Cannot find module
>   'slack-client'

tried to perform 'npm install slack-client' but then i get another error :
see another question in [Hubot with slack adapter - cannot perform rtm.start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253381/hubot-with-slack-adapter-cannot-perform-rtm-start)

Comment: Have you tried another fresh install?

Comment: check if slack client is added to package.json

Answer (score 1):

@slack/client needs higher npm versions. It worked for me on npm 5.3.0 but not 3.3.12. try uninstalling node and retry with latest npm version

Answer (score 1):

It's works for me to use stable version install hubot slack.
For CentOS 7:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.13.1/install.sh | bash
source ~/.bash_profile
nvm list-remote
nvm install v8.4.0
nvm alias default v8.4.0
npm install -g npm
npm install -g yo generator-hubot
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to execute the command inside the bin folder of hubot. Instead, go to the parent of bin folder, then execute like this:
**./bin/hubot -a slack**